# Google Search History - linking across multiple accounts?

Tags: google-search, google-account, privacy, google-search-history

Does Google link searches across multiple accounts? For example, if I signed out of my account, then searched Google, would Google log the fact it was likely the accountholder of the account just signed out that did that search? Further, I am aware that Google stores searches performed when not signed in along with the corresponding IP address indefinitely (although it removes the last octet after 18 months), but what about when I delete search history associated with my account? Will Google permanently erase that history, or will it still keep a log saying this IP address performed this search, but without any details on which account in particular did that search?